# How to insert commas into a number?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I've found such an example of using `String.format()` in a book:

```
package stringFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = String.format("%, d", 1000000000);
        System.out.println(test);
    } 
}
```

According to the book the output should be: `1,000,000,000`. But when I run the code I only get `1 000 000 000` without the commas. Why? how can I get it with commas?

[image: output picture]

Comment: It works fine in my side

Comment: Your output is different because of your locale. If you put `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);` before the call to `format`, the output would match that of the book. Seems that your OS has french-like number format rules.

Comment: @ernest_k thank you so much! this answers my question perfectly!

Comment: The book should at least have mentioned that `String.format` is locale-sensitive and that the actual output may differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reproduce the problem with `Locale.FRANCE`:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);

String test = String.format("%, d", 1000000000);
System.out.println(test); //  1 000 000 000
```

You can avoid this with `Locale.US`:

```
String test = String.format(Locale.US, "%, d", 1000000000);

or

Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
String test = String.format("%, d", 1000000000);
```

Comment: but what about the example? is it completely wrong then? why doesn't it work?

Comment: @CuteShark See the comment of  ernest_k.

Comment: Yes, I've already checked it and it works. So now I have no questions left about this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the format in Java in the link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

For your problem, you can fix:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String s = "1000000000";

   System.out.format("%,"+s.length()+"d%n", Long.parseLong(s));

}
```

Hope to helpfull!